# A nice description for $t^{k-1}B_{cr}^+/t^kB_{cr}^+$?

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, hodge-theory

When $t$ is a uniformizer of the integral de Rham period ring, $B_{dR}^+$, there is an isomorphism $t^{k-1}B_{dR}^+/t^{k}B_{dR}^+\cong \mathbb{C}_p(k-1)$. Is there a nice description for $t^{k-1}B_{cr}^+/t^kB_{cr}^+$?